# Solr, can you use multiple schema.xml for a document?

Tags: solr, indexing, document

Can I use different format (schema.xml) for a document (like car document)?

So that I can use different index to query the same class of documents differently?

(OK.. I can use two instances of Solr, but.. that's the only way? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one schema is possible for a Core.
You can always have different Cores within the same solr with the Multicore configuration.
However, if you have the same entity and want to query it differently, you can have the same schema.xml to hold the values different fields and different field types (Check [copyfield](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields)) and have different query handler to have weighted queries depending upon the needs.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can only have one schema file per Solr core.

Each core uses its own schema file so if you want to have two different schema files then either set -up a 2nd Solr core or run another instance of Solr